# Top program returns fewer values from ruby than bash on linux

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to incorporate the results of top into a ruby program. But top behaves differently when called in a subshell from ruby than when run in the shell directly. Specifically, it excludes many results when run from ruby.

For example, running `top -bn1 | wc -l` in bash returns "133". Running the same command from irb using backticks returns "17".

Why is there a difference between calling top from the shell and from a sub-shell? How can I get top's complete output in a ruby script?

## Notes

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (precise). This problem doesn't occur on mac OS X, which provides an entirely different version of top.

Using the "-d" delay flag doesn't seem to change the behavior. Nor does increasing the number of iterations.

I'm aware that ps returns many of the same statistics as top, but I'm specifically interested in top's estimation of CPU usage, which is calculated differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `top` is respecting your terminal's size when run inside ruby. I bet your terminal size is 17 lines high. Try deleting the LINES entry in the ENV hash:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> %x{top -bn1 | wc -l}
=> "36\n"
irb(main):002:0> ENV.delete 'LINES'
=> "36"
irb(main):003:0> %x{top -bn1 | wc -l}
=> "169\n"
```

If you want to find out how many processes are running, from ruby you can write:

```
num = Dir.glob('/proc/*').select {|d| File.directory? d and d.match(/\/\d+$/)}.length
```

For CPU usage, perhaps:

```
idle = %x{vmstat 1 2}.split[-2].to_i
usage = 100 - idle
```

Comment: And it might help to adjust `ENV['COLUMNS']` to some big number like `'10000'`.

Comment: Yup, the terminal size was the problem. Thanks!